# Infinitely simple polygon solipsism

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, dissection

*Solipsism* —
The self is all that can be known to exist.

[image]

Above is a
[simple polygonal region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon)
divided into infinitely many different-sized copies of itself.
 
Each copy is √2 = 1.414...
times as large as the next smaller one
(in terms of linear scale, not area).
 
If the largest copy is removed,
the remaining polygonal region is a scaled-down version of the original.

**Can you find another simple polygon
that has *4 or more sides*
and can be divided into
infinitely many different-sized copies of itself,
where the original polygonal region is geometrically similar
to what remains
if the largest component copy is removed?**

The open-ended goal is
a maximum successive-size ratio as close as possible to 1.

Reflection is allowed.
 
Each copy size occurs only once.
 
Polygons in this puzzle have _finitely_ many vertices.
 
Note that the goal is to minimize the _maximum_,
not average or smallest,
ratio between any two successively sized copies.
 
The large composite polygon is not included in these ratios.
 
A neat solution with only right angles
and a maximum ratio less than 1.3 is known at pose time.

<sub>(This puzzle is similar, but with different conditions, to
[*Unreflected Infinitely simple polygon reflexivity*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49151/unreflected-infinitely-simple-polygon-reflexivity).)</sub>

Comment: Why a simple insets of polygons will not work. The relation and removal of polygons need to be better defined.

Comment: You could just have insets of similar polygons... and remove the largest

Comment: That would leave a hole. Or did I understand?

Comment: Not if they are nested and you remove the largest.

Comment: The polygons are nested? Larger attached to the smaller? To maintain similarity it seems that the ratio is given. Do you know the solution?

Comment: You require that every time a nested rectangle will be left - each rectangle, based on your drawing - share a side with another rectangle and all similar - means that the ratio of the sides of the rectangle is $sqrt\{2}$. There are infinite such families of 4 - all parallelograms that are resulting from selecting any desired angle between the sides.

Comment: Good generalization of infinitely many parallelogram solutions
with a ratio of √2, @Moti!
I would gladly vote approval if you post that,
but at least one other solution has a ratio closer to 1.
(By the way, the puzzle statement has been slightly clarified
 from our earlier comments, mainly to use the term ["polygonal region"](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMT668.Folders.F97/Cowart/lesson1/lesson%231.html)
 instead of "polygon." As such, they cannot be nested.)

Comment: @humn [This paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0012365X10004176/1-s2.0-S0012365X10004176-main.pdf?_tid=fb34bf9a-f88f-11e6-9cbf-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1487720976_d526f6af91b85697fa2f8f3c62bceb30) seems to show that your intended right-angled solution is optimal because no others are possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution with ratio $\varphi^\frac12\approx1.27201965$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio:

> Set $x=\varphi^{-\frac12}$. Then:
> [image]
> The numbers work out due to how the golden ratio works. The outer numbers define the dimensions for the entire hexagon. Note that I did not come up with this polygon; it is called the Golden Bee and was originally devised by Karl Scherer in [his 1987 book](http://karlscherer.com/Mybooks/bkrintro.html). This is probably optimal.

Comment: Right on!  (Incidentally, _Golden Bee_ was originally _published_, not devised, in the mid/late 1980s. I called it _PP_ in 1983 and assumed that others had found it too, as [turned out to be the case](http://goldenbpuzzles.com/insights/the-history-and-properties-of-the-golden-b/).)